# How to use record data to trigger a webservice call and store result in field?

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

My flow is to have a trigger on the contact object, make a REST API to external service using the data from the contact record, get a reply and store the information back into the record. However, I am hitting an issue that I just don't seem to understand why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Trigger:

```
trigger ContactNumVerify on Contact (after update, after insert) {

if (Trigger.isUpdate) {

    // create list to hold the Contact Record ID
    List<String> recordId = new List<String>();

    // create new Contact to pull the Contact ID
    for (Contact cnt : Trigger.new) {

        // new instance of the account is set to a
        Contact c = new Contact();

        // set the Id to the Id of the new Contact
        c.Id = cnt.Id;

        // add the contact ID to the recordId List
        recordId.add(c.Id);

        // call Webservice 
        ContactNumVerifyCallout.makeCallout(recordId); 

    }

}
```

Class:

```
public class ContactNumVerifyCallout {

@future(callout=true)
public static void makeCallout(List<ID> recordId){
    
    List<Contact> cnt = [Select id, Phone,international_format__c, MailingCountry from Contact where id IN :recordId];
    
    
    for(Contact c: cnt){
        String phoneNumber = c.Phone;
        // Remove non-digit characters
        String phoneNumberDigits = phoneNumber.replaceAll('\\D+','');
        
        
        if(c.international_format__c==null){
            
            String URI = 'http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key=381bbd3571eb98047d940f3181&number='+phoneNumberDigits+'&country_code='+c.MailingCountry; 
            System.debug('URI:'+URI);
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(URI);
            request.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            
            // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
                Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                
                System.debug('RESULTS'+results);   
                String international_format = (String) results.get('international_format');
                System.debug('Received the following international_format:' + international_format);
                
                c.international_format__c=international_format; 
                
                System.debug('Contact value'+c.international_format__c);
                
            }
            
        }
        
        //update the record with new value
        update c;
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Error:
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0031E00002TNxf3QAD; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ContactNumVerify: execution of AfterUpdate

Comment: The error seems incomplete. Can you post the complete message. Also you may want to revisit your approach after this error is resolved as the current one is bound to exceed Future calls limit when you get more records in trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a recursion issue.

That is in the same trigger context, an update kicks the trigger again and this process goes in a never-ending loop.

You can easily fix this by comparing old and new record fields before you perform the callout. The below is an example assuming its phone field you want to trigger this process for.

```
for (Contact cnt : Trigger.new) {

   if(cnt.Phone != Trigger.oldMap.get(cnt.Id).Phone) {

   }

}
```

Also, there are other techniques like using the static boolean that's documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332407&type=1&mode=1)